# Best Way to convert the data in the format

Tags: python

I have a data structure that is something like this

```
my_data = [
    ('Continent1','Country1','State1'),
    ('Continent1','Country1','State2'),
    ('Continent1','Country2','State1'),
    ('Continent1','Country2','State2'),
    ('Continent1','Country2','State3','City1',11111)
]
```

With the input not limited to State it can be narrowed down further to something like

`Cotinent` ==> `Country` ==> `State` ==> `City` ==> `Zip` (With `State`, `City` and `Zip`) being optional fields.
I wish to convert it to a json like provided on the fields shared in payload

```
{
    "Regions": [{
        "Continent": 'Continent1',
        "Country": "Country1",
        "State": "state1"
    }, {
        "Continent": 'Continent1',
        "Country": "Country1",
        "State": "state2"
    }, {
        "Continent": 'Continent1',
        "Country": "Country2",
        "State": "state1"
    }, {
        "Continent": 'Continent1',
        "Country": "Country1",
        "State": "state2"
    }, {
        "Continent": 'Continent1',
        "Country": "Country1",
        "State": "state3",
        "City": "City1",
        "zip": "11111",
    }]
}
```

Any pseudo code/approach for the same would be appreciated which would support the output based on multiple inputs.

Comment: This is not hard, it's just brute force, line by line.  For each entry in your list, append a dict.

Comment: Thats what is bothering me, if the data is too large, how do I get best performance out of it

Comment: Why would performance be an issue?  If the lines you have fit in memory, then it's going to take no time at all to do this conversion.  This is not the kind of operation you can "optimize".  Are you going to write it to file as a JSON when you're done?

Comment: This would shared to another API as a response in JSON. It is a small part of some complex transactions API is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
keys = ["Continent", "Country", "State", "City", "Zip"]
transformed_data = {
    "Regions": [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in my_data]
}
```